# Problemas de configuración del editor Atom.io

Tags: php, atom-editor

Estoy probando el editor Atom y me ocurre que, luego de instalar algunos plugins, me arroja permanentemente errores del tipo:

> 'php' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process.

Instalé el plugin beautify entre otros, lo curioso es que con Sublime Text (el que estaba usando hasta este momento) ni con Brackets (lo instalé a partir que encontré estos errores en Atom) ese plugin produce este error.

Estoy trabajando en Windows 7 y uso Wampserver. Lo más extraño es que en una notebook tengo instalado Linux con XAMPP y allí también se reproducen los mismos errores...

¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo se puede solucionar este error?

[image: error 2]
[image: error 1]

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes cuando haces `where.exe php` en la línea de comandos?

Comment: Estoy con Windows 7 y wampserver... por lo tanto el php esta dentro del wampserver asi que no se si el where sirve de algo... pero me arroja un error que dice "no se pudo encontrar ningun archivo para los patrones dados" pero probé con otros ejecutables y ni siquiera encuentra el wampserver, ni el photoshop, ni el visual studio... osea no se, me enconntró el brackets y el notepad...

Comment: ¿Has añadido el directorio que contiene PHP al path? Debería ser algo como `C:\wamp\bin\php\php<version>`

Comment: estoy revisando las variables de entorno y no esta declarado... y como tengo que hacerlo ? necesito agregar algo más ademas del path a php ? Puedo tener un path para más de una version ? o solo me conviene tener la ultima ?

Comment: Prueba a agregar sólo ese directorio y reinicia Atom, a ver si eso hace algo.

Comment: ahora me arroja el error de que no encuentra el php-cs-fixer y que lo coloque en el path...

Comment: no se si tengo que reiniciar la PC porque sigue arrojando el error de que php no esta instalado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Debes tener instalado "php" por lo general al instalar los
   servidores Wamp o Xampp se instalan por defecto.
2. Tener descargado el archivo "php-cs-fixer.phar"
       https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer
3. En el CMD ejecutar este comando: where.exe php
4. Se obtiene un path, ese path copiar en: Abrir Atom Packages/Atom Beautify/Settings/Executables/PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. En la misma carpeta donde se encuentra el php.exe copiar el archivo "php-cs-fixer.phar"
6. Volver a realizar el proceso anterior con el CMD y el Atom en PHP-CS-Fixer"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto !!! Muchísimas gracias !!!

Answer (score -1):

El problema es algún paquete de autocomplete-php.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta

Comment: si, he probado pero no con muy buenos resultados... es una pena porque atom es un programa muy lindo, me gusta mucho...

Comment: si, he probado pero no con muy buenos resultados... es una pena porque atom es un programa muy lindo, me gusta mucho...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]